# How to make a upload script in one page only?

Tags: php

Can anyone give a sample of an upload script that will process the upload and the validations in one page? Or the concept/idea on how to make it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why does it need to be in one page?

Comment: Errors?  Can you explain exactly what is going on?

Comment: Do you mean one page as in one php file, or one page as in an ajax uploader that doesnt refresh the entire page in the browser.

Comment: @prodigitalson YES one page in ONE PHP FILE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in one PHP file. The general concept:

```
<?php

     if (empty($_FILES)) {   // or check for $_POST["submit-button"]

          // print form
          ?>...<input type=file name=upload>...<?php

     }
     else {

          // process form
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], ...);

     }
```

All the other details are mentioned in http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php, and in the heaps of existing tutorials on PHP file uploads.